# I need a hint to prove that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} 2^{\frac{1}{n}} = 1$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I need a hint on the following problems:

1. Prove that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} 2^{\frac{1}{n}} = 1$
2. Let $A$ and $B$ be subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ such that $\forall a \in A$ and $\forall b \in B$ we got $a \leq b$. $$\sup A = \inf B \Leftrightarrow b - a < \epsilon$$

These problems are basic, but I didn't manage to prove them. Thank you for your precious time!

Comment: as $n \to \infty$ then $\frac{1}{n} \to 0$ this implies $2^{0}=1$

Comment: for the first problem, you may consider
$$2^{1/n} = \exp\left(\frac{\ln(2)}{n}\right)$$
then use the fact that the exponential function is continuous and
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{n} = 0$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For first part just letting $n \to \infty$ gives you the answer because of $ n \to \infty \Rightarrow \frac{1}{n} \to 0 \Rightarrow \lim\limits_{n \to \infty}2^{\frac{1}{n}} = 2^0 = 1$.

For the second part, we prove both implications one by one.

First, assume sup $A$ = inf $B$. Then, for any $\epsilon > 0, \exists a \in A,b \in B  $ such that $ \sup A -a < \epsilon/2 $ and $b-\inf B <\epsilon/2 \Rightarrow b-\sup A < \epsilon/2 \Rightarrow b-a < \epsilon.$

Secondly, assume for any $\epsilon >0, \exists\ a\in A, b\in B \ \text{such that}\  b-a < \epsilon.$ 
Now, $\sup A \ge a, \forall \ a \in A $ and $\inf B \le b, \forall\ b \in B.$ Also $a \le b\ \forall a\in A,b \in B. $ So, $-\sup A \le -a \Rightarrow \inf B-\sup A \le b-a < \epsilon.$ But above equation holds for any arbitrary $\epsilon >0.$ So can you see why $\sup A=\inf B$ ??

Comment: For the first part that is sufficient? There must be a more formal way of showing that  that's my doubt after all

Comment: yeah, thats sufficient. Though you could prove via other methods also, this is the simplest and most straightforward.

Comment: And yes, I can see why, but I was struggling along the way hahahaha thank you very much man!

Comment: Consider upvoting/accepting the answer so that the question may be closed. :)